# How to change the size of the pdf in prestashop using TPDF

Tags: pdf, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I want the size of the paper to be increased to A3 OR OR C4 (width to be increased)
I tried below but no change is there anyway to change the size of the pdf generated?

```
public function generatePDF($object, $template)
{

    switch($template) {
        case PDF::TEMPLATE_ETICKET:
            $format = 'C3'; // Replace with your desired size
            break;
        default:
            $format =  'A4'; // Replace with normal size
    }
    $pdf = new PDF($object, $template, Context::getContext()->smarty,'P', $format);
    //d($pdf);
    $pdf->render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file PDFGenerator.php in override/classes/pdf.

in to PDFGenerator.php insert:

```
<?php 
class PDFGenerator extends PDFGeneratorCore
{
    public function __construct($use_cache = false, $orientation = 'P')
    {
        parent::__construct($orientation, 'mm', 'A3', true, 'UTF-8', $use_cache, false); /*Replace A3 with the size you prefer */
        $this->setRTL(Context::getContext()->language->is_rtl);
    }
}
```

delete cache/class_index.php